# Command "python manage.py shell" pops up error message

Tags: python, django, windows, powershell

Whenever I enter `python manage.py shell` in Windows PowerShell ISE, I get an error message:

```
Python: Python 3.6.1.....    
At line:1 char:1
+ python manage.py shell
+ ________
+category info: Notspecified: [], RemoteException
+FullyQualifiedErrorId : Nativecommanderror

Type "help", "copyright"....
```

Comment: Guessing that is sending data to the error stream which is common for many exes. PowerShell is just reacting as it would to any error. Does it work outside of that? Need to find a dupe that talks about this and redirection possibly.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. The shell doesn't pop up

Comment: There is more to that error yes? What are the lines between your command and that text you show?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you go up one level with `cd ..` and then try `python thefolder\manage.py shell`?

Comment: The message is coming from python. I thinks you arguments are malformed so it wants you to check help. That text is sent down the error stream which is why PowerShell is treating it that way. I don't know Python enough to help beyond that.

Comment: I got the same behavior when I changed from PS to PS ISE.